# naming issues in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, naming-conventions

What can be the possible issues if the DataTable name is the same with one of its column name?
When can we be likely to face those issues?

e.g
DataTable Code has a column name Code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the hierarchical structure of DataTable there should be no issue.
Because each column is stored in a separate object and each of these objects are stored in a collection within the datatable.

The only issue could be that it confuses the people who are reading your code.